# Modeling a Skirt with Outside Influence

Tags: modeling, mesh

Thank you for taking some time to check out my query.

I'm currently modelling a character that is wearing a skirt who also has very long hair which rests along her back. (This is also my first time modelling anything so please be gentle if this is a really stupid question.) In the future I know I'll have to rig the character to move and I'll probably have to have some controllers on the skirt in order to allow it to flow in animations. I've modeled the skirt to form to the body as if the weight from the hair is upon it, but would this be correct?

Should I be modeling this section as if physics are applied to it and have the skirt slightly deformed? Or should I model the skirt as if it were a stand alone object and have it unaffected by the hair? (This would mean I'd have to fix the skirt whenever I needed to animate the character, right?)

Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have picked a very ambitious modelling project to start with.

To avoid weird glitches, you should model the skirt in a neutral pose. In other words, don't worry about the hair. This logic applies to almost anything that gets animated. For example you should model the hands in a position that is neither completely flat nor clamped into a fist.

Good luck.